# Perpendicular polarizer filters for solar power conversion?

Tags: polarization

If two perpendicular polarizer filters are placed on top of each other, they would almost all of the (visible and UV) light that falls on them.  This could be used to absorb sunlight, which would heat up the filters. Then this heat could be converted to electricity in a steam turbine. I seem to be wrong somewhere, please help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of polarizer. Many simply reflect most of the rejected polarization’s power rather than absorbing it. It would be easier to coat the absorber with a rough carbon layer to absorb >99% of the light.

Answer (score 0):

Something painted black would also absorb nearly all the light falling on it. You could use the heat from that to make electricity, if you like. This is just a type of heat engine, there is no contradiction whatsoever.

Comment: intense beam of light starts to reflect off black paint. Would the polarised filters be able to immitate vanatablack or a better black body ?

Comment: @adi No, absorption filters also have some reflection. In general they would be much worse.